# How can I convert Stock Exchange json response to Python Object?

Tags: python, json

I am getting below response from Python API call to stock exchange to get the recent transaction price:

```
{'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 1594, 'ltp': 660.7, 'ltt': 1588069745, 'ltq': 2, 'volume': 7296594, 'best_bid_price': 660.7, 'best_bid_quantity': 4864, 'best_ask_price': 0.0, 'best_ask_quantity': 0, 'total_buy_quantity': 4864, 'total_sell_quantity': 0, 'atp': 659.87, 'exchange_time_stamp': 1588069757, 'open': 673.0, 'high': 677.0, 'low': 653.05, 'close': 658.0, 'yearly_high': 847.0, 'yearly_low': 509.25, 'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=1594, symbol='INFY', name='INFOSYS LIMITED', expiry=None, lot_size=None)}
```

I want to retrieve each item like ltp,ltt,volume ect.
Tried below:

```
msg="{'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 1594, 'ltp': 660.7, 'ltt': 1588069745, 'ltq': 2, 'volume': 7296594, 'best_bid_price': 660.7, 'best_bid_quantity': 4864, 'best_ask_price': 0.0, 'best_ask_quantity': 0, 'total_buy_quantity': 4864, 'total_sell_quantity': 0, 'atp': 659.87, 'exchange_time_stamp': 1588069757, 'open': 673.0, 'high': 677.0, 'low': 653.05, 'close': 658.0, 'yearly_high': 847.0, 'yearly_low': 509.25, 'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=1594, symbol='INFY', name='INFOSYS LIMITED', expiry=None, lot_size=None)}"
  
res=json.dumps(msg)
res2=json.loads(res)  
print(type(res))
print(type(res2))
print(res2['ltp'])
```

- 

```
Output :
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(res2['ltp'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

This is not converting the above json data to Python list.

How can I parse this data?

Comment: Why did you use `json.dumps`?

Comment: Did you mean: res=json.loads(msg) ?

Answer (score 3):

That:

```
msg="{'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 1594, 'ltp': 660.7, 'ltt': 1588069745, 'ltq': 2, 'volume': 7296594, 'best_bid_price': 660.7, 'best_bid_quantity': 4864, 'best_ask_price': 0.0, 'best_ask_quantity': 0, 'total_buy_quantity': 4864, 'total_sell_quantity': 0, 'atp': 659.87, 'exchange_time_stamp': 1588069757, 'open': 673.0, 'high': 677.0, 'low': 653.05, 'close': 658.0, 'yearly_high': 847.0, 'yearly_low': 509.25, 'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=1594, symbol='INFY', name='INFOSYS LIMITED', expiry=None, lot_size=None)}"
```

is **not** JSON - note that it does have keys enclosed in `'` instead of `"`, `None` rather than `null` and instrument value does look like Python creation of object. If you try to `json.loads(msg)` it will result in error. Do you have documentation for used *Python API*? If yes check what it is supposed to return.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the object and append it to a new list:

```
new_list = []
res2=json.loads(msg)
for item in res2:
    new_list.append(item)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: I tried this not working.as res2 itself is a string.

Comment: @Manoj So I am assuming that you are getting a string as a response from your call. Double check to see if you are calling to the right address

Answer (score 0):

Your initial `msg`is already a string, When you do `json.dumps(msg)`, it created a string inside a string ,when you did `json.loads()`, it loaded the inside string, so  `type(res)` is `str`

```
msg="{'exchange': 'NSE', 'token': 1594, 'ltp': 660.7, 'ltt': 1588069745, 'ltq': 2, 'volume': 7296594, 'best_bid_price': 660.7, 'best_bid_quantity': 4864, 'best_ask_price': 0.0, 'best_ask_quantity': 0, 'total_buy_quantity': 4864, 'total_sell_quantity': 0, 'atp': 659.87, 'exchange_time_stamp': 1588069757, 'open': 673.0, 'high': 677.0, 'low': 653.05, 'close': 658.0, 'yearly_high': 847.0, 'yearly_low': 509.25, 'instrument': Instrument(exchange='NSE', token=1594, symbol='INFY', name='INFOSYS LIMITED', expiry=None, lot_size=None)}"

#res=json.dumps(msg)
res2=json.loads(res)  
#print(type(res))
print(type(res2))
print(res2['ltp'])
```

This should work. just comment out `json.dumps()` or do `json.loads()` twice

Comment: Below is the how the response is coming from websocket

def event_handler_quote_update(message):
    global ltp
    global msg
    ltp = message['ltp']
    msg=message

After this call i am able to see the correct value of ltp. But this message contains many more items. I am not able to get that.

Comment: I replaced single quote with double quote and tried twice json.loads. getting error